# Crepant resolution of quotient singularities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, resolution-of-singularities

Let $G$ be a finite subgroup of $U(m)$ such that $G$ acts freely on $\mathbb C^m \setminus \{0\}$.

If $\mathbb C^m/G$ has a crepant resolution, can we necessarily derive that $G \subset SU(m)$?

Comment: You need to exclude the case that $m$ equals $1$.  More precisely, the correct hypothesis is that the non-free locus has no irreducible component of codimension equal to $1$.